# Error al devolver una vista ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Al intentar crear un producto interactuando con la interfaz web me da error, he intentado pasar la lista como INumerable pero el error persiste.

La vista creada es genérica, es decir la creada por asp.net con la plantilla "List":

```
 @model IEnumerable<Martín_N_AUT01_00.Models.Product>

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
  @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Category)
    </th>
    <th></th>
</tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Category)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.Id }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.Id }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.Id })
    </td>
</tr>
```

}

Información de **error** proporcionada por el navegador:

> El elemento de modelo pasado al diccionario es de tipo
>   'System.Web.Mvc.ViewResult', pero este diccionario requiere un
>   elemento de modelo de tipo 'Martín_N_AUT01_00.Models.Product'.

Código en el controlador:

```
namespace Martín_N_AUT01_00.Controllers {
public class ProductController : Controller {
    // GET: Product

    public List<Models.Product> Model = new List<Models.Product>();



    public ActionResult Create() {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Models.Product product) {
        Model.Add(product);
        return View (Index());
    }
    public ActionResult Index() {
        return View(Model);
    }
 }

}
```

Código en el modelo:

```
using System.Web;

namespace Martín_N_AUT01_00.Models
{
    public class Product
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public String Name { get; set; }
        public String Category { get; set; }
    }
}
```

La duda está planteada sobre un ejercicio académico.

Comment: Te recomiendo no utilizar tildes/acentos ni caracteres únicos del castellano en tu código

Comment: Tienes que convertir el modelo que recibes al enviado

Comment: Podrías ser un poco más concreto respecto a cómo puedo convertirlo o dónde puedo encontrar documentación útil. Muchas gracias

Comment: @nauumb Podrías indicar el código de la Vista?.

Comment: Revisa este workshop, te será de mucha utilidad: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6LZG76aLykY

Comment: He implementado la vista que he utilizado.

Answer (score 2):

El problema se encuenta en esta linea

```
return View (Index());
```

No puedes poner un action como model de una view

Si necesitas redireccionar se utiliza el `RedirectToAction` indicando el nombre del action al cual quieres que se redireccione despeus del post

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Models.Product product) {
    Model.Add(product);
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

[ASP.NET MVC - View() vs RedirectToAction() vs Redirect() Methods](https://www.dotnettricks.com/learn/mvc/return-view-vs-return-redirecttoaction-vs-return-redirect-vs-return-redirecttoroute)

Tampoco deberias definir una lista publica a nivel del controller, esta linea

```
public List<Models.Product> Model = new List<Models.Product>();
```

esta mal

Deberias quitarla y definir el model en el action ya que en asp.net mvc no hay estado

```
public ActionResult Index() {
    List<Models.Product> products= new List<Models.Product>();
    return View(products);
}
```

El objeto `Model` ya estara disponible en la view, o sea en el .cshtml automaticamente

Si quieres mantener los datos del lado del servidor deberias usar el objeto `Session` ya que recuerda asp.net mvc no mantiene estado de las variables

```
public ActionResult Index() {
    List<Models.Product> products= new List<Models.Product>();

    if(Session["products"] != null){
      products = (List<Models.Product>)Session["products"];
    } else {
       Session["products"] = products;
    }

    return View(products);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Models.Product product) {
    List<Models.Product> products = (List<Models.Product>)Session["products"];
    products.Add(product)
    return View("Index", products);
}
```

Comment: Excelente explicación, ni yo lo haría mejor ;. Pero lo de a sesión está algo raro. Si te das cuenta cada vez que entras  a `Index()` creas un nuevo `List` de `products` y lo pasas a la sesión, por lo tanto sobrescribes  el que ya había.

Comment: es verdad, edite el ejemplo para agregar la validacion que verifique si es que ya hay previamente datos en la session, asi no se sobreescriben

Answer (score 1):

Aporto otra solución que funciona definiendo la lista a nivel de controlador, pero en este caso con un modificador de acceso privado y además estática.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Martín_N_AUT01_00.Controllers
{
public class ProductController : Controller
{
    // GET: Product

    private static List<Models.Product> products = new List<Models.Product>();
    private static int idIncrement = 0;

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(products);
    }

    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Models.Product product)
    {
        products.Add(product);
        return View("Index", products);
    }
}
}
```